# Cloning arrays to hold original values for future use

Tags: java, arrays, clone

I have several  object arrays for different sets of the object order.

```
public class MyObject extends Location{
    String color;
    int location;
}
```

i have the following arrays in a separate class:

```
public class Location{
    MyObject[] first;  /// initiated in main as new MyObject[20]; and holding values...
    MyObject[] second;
    MyObject[] third;
    MyObject[] temp;   /// to be used later to hold the original array within a method
```

in class location i send one of the arrays (excluding temp) to another method:

```
makeMove(first//for example//, blah blah blah)

public boolean makeMove(MyObject[] currentArray, blah blah blah){
    temp = first.clone(); // I clone in order to save the original values in case the next method == false
    if(isLegal(currentArray, blah, blah){
        currentArray[x]=currentArray[y]; currentArray[y]=null; // This does change the values in the original array "first".
        if(anotherCheck(currentArray, blah)
            currentArray = temp.clone(); // restores cuurentArray values but not "first".
    }
}
```

The last line is supposed to return the original values stored in the "temp" array i cloned from currentArray (which is supposed to hold the original array i sent to the method - in this case "first"). The problem is that it restores everything to "currentArray" but not to the original array sent to the method - "first".

Is there any way to get it to change the original "first" array sent to the method?

Comment: `currentArray[x]==currentArray[y]; currentArray[y]==null;` - this doesn't do anything. You used the `==` equality comparison operator, not the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: @user2357112 That wouldn't even compile so it's probably not what OP actually has.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Oh yeah, you're right. I forgot Java syntactically prohibits side-effect-free operators in such positions.

Comment: Can you show the actual method? It's difficult to tell which mistakes you made in your real code and which mistakes are irrelevant. In any case, `currentArray = temp.clone()` won't modify any arrays. It makes the `currentArray` variable point to a new array. If you want to restore changes to an array, I recommend either keeping track of the specific changes you made and undoing the assignments, or not making the changes until you know you won't undo them. You can also use a for loop or System.arraycopy to copy the clone into the original, but it's probably not the best way.

Comment: Sorry. The original code is of course using the "=" operator and not "==" equality. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

After finding no solution what I finally did was a for loop:

```
public boolean makeMove(MyObject[] currentArray, blah blah blah){
    temp = first.clone(); // I clone in order to save the original values in case the next method == false
    if(isLegal(currentArray, blah, blah){
        currentArray[x]=currentArray[y]; currentArray[y]=null; // This does change the values in the original array "first".
        if(anotherCheck(currentArray, blah)
            for(int i=0; i<currentArray.length;i++)
                currentArray[i]=temp[i];
    }
}
```

And well... this works for me!
What do you think?